# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^5+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I want to check, whether $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^5+1}}$ converges or diverges.

I tried to use Leibniz's test :

$|a_n|= \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^5+1}} = \frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^4(n+\frac{1}{n^4})}} = \frac{n^2}{n^2\sqrt{n+\frac{1}{n^4}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+\frac{1}{n^4}}}$

So $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}{{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+\frac{1}{n^4}}} = 0}} $

$1>|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}|= \frac{(n+1)^2}{\sqrt{(n+1)^5+1}} \frac{\sqrt{n^5+1}}{n^2}= \frac{2n+1 \sqrt{n^5+1}}{\sqrt{(n+1)^5+1}}= \frac{n^2+2n+1 \sqrt{n+\frac {1}{n^4}}}{(n+1)^2\sqrt{n+1+1}} = \frac {\sqrt{n+\frac {1}{n^4}}}{\sqrt{n+2}}$

So $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^5+1}}$ converges.

Could somebody please check my solution?

Comment: What you wrote is sufficient to show that the sequence of absolute values is decreasing (**except** at the very beginning). However, there is a lack of explanation. It would be much better not to have a $1\gt$ at the beginning of your penultimate line, and instead explain why the expression at the end of that line is $\lt 1$.

Comment: To my knowledge you verified the correct conditions for leibniz, though your verification that $a_n$ is decreasing appears to contain errors starting with $\frac{(2n+1) \sqrt{n^5+1}}{\sqrt{(n+1)^5+1}}$, you can't factor out $(n+1)^2$ in the denominator as you do in the next step.

Comment: One line before the last one, how did you get the second equality? I think it is wrong...

Comment: ... = $\frac{n^2+2n+1 \sqrt{n+\frac {1}{n^4}}}{(n+1)^2\sqrt{(n+1)+ \frac{1}{(n+1)^4}}} = \frac {\sqrt{n+\frac {1}{n^4}}}{\sqrt{(n+1)+ \frac{1}{(n+1)^4}}}$ And this should be $>1$ because $\sqrt{(n+1)+ \frac{1}{(n+1)^4}} > \sqrt{(n)+ \frac{1}{n^4}}$

Comment: @DonAntonio i reduced $n^2$ of $(n+1)^2$ with $n^2$ in the denominator

Comment: That's incorrect, @fear.xD, as it is **not** multiplying in the numerator!

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$(n^5+1)^{-1/2}=\frac{1}{n^{5/2}}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^5}\right)^{-1/2}=\frac{1}{n^{5/2}}\left(1+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)\right)$$
hence
$$(-1)^n\frac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^5+1}}=\underbrace{\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{1/2}}}_{=u_n}+\underbrace{O\left(\frac{1}{n^{11/2}}\right)}_{=v_n}$$
the series $\displaystyle\sum_n u_n$ is convergent by the Leibniz theorem and the series $\displaystyle\sum_n v_n$ is also convergent by comparison with the Riemann series. Conclude.

Comment: Have a nice time there. :-)

Comment: Wherever you're going Sami, have a good time! And...take +1 with you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Leibitz, but the terms are decreasing in absolute value, and the series is alternating, so you are good.

Answer (score 0):

The convergence of $$\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n \dfrac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^5+1}}$$ can be concluded based on alternating test. The general result is termed as [generalized alternating test or Dirichlet test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) and is based on [Abel partial summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts). We will prove the generalized statement, though this is a bit of a overkill for this problem it is as easy to prove as the alternating test.

Consider the sum $S_N = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^N a(n)b(n)$. Let $A(n) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^N a(n)$. If $b(n) \downarrow 0$ and $A(n)$ is bounded, then the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a(n)b(n)$ converges.

First note that from Abel summation, we have that
$$\sum_{n=1}^N a(n) b(n) = \sum_{n=1}^N b(n)(A(n)-A(n-1)) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} b(n) A(n) - \sum_{n=1}^N b(n)A(n-1)\\
= \sum_{n=1}^{N} b(n) A(n) - \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} b(n+1)A(n) = b(N) A(N) - b(1)A(0) + \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} A(n) (b(n)-b(n+1))$$
Now if $A(n)$ is bounded i.e. $\vert A(n) \vert \leq M$ and $b(n)$ is decreasing, then we have that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \left \vert A(n) \right \vert (b(n)-b(n+1)) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} M (b(n)-b(n+1))\\ = M (b(1) - b(N)) \leq Mb(1)$$
Hence, we have that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \left \vert A(n) \right \vert (b(n)-b(n+1))$ converges and hence $$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} A(n)  (b(n)-b(n+1))$$ converges absolutely. Now since
$$\sum_{n=1}^N a(n) b(n) = b(N) A(N) + \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} A(n) (b(n)-b(n+1))$$
we have that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^N a(n)b(n)$ converges.

In your case, $a(n) = (-1)^n$. Hence, $$A(N) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n$$which is clearly bounded.

Also, $b(n) = \dfrac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^5+1}}$ is a monotone decreasing sequence converging to $0$.

Hence, we have that $$\sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n \dfrac{n^2}{\sqrt{n^5+1}}$$ converges.